# SQL Server - Key Lookup on Nested Loop (no related index)

Tags: sql-server

My execution plan is SQL Server is showing a Key Lookup (Clustered) on PK_Appointments. There is no Index above this on the execution plan (usually I would create a covering index, or include columns on the linked index from the plan) so I'm unsure how to fix this particular key lookup.

[image]

The query I'm running has a union and 24 joins on it.

Profiler status reads: CPU 203, Reads 1971, Writes 0, Duration 359.

It may not seem major, but his query is run a lot on specific areas of the application, so looking to see if I can make it return faster.

Comment: Your question is unclear as it doesn't specify the plan operator used to retrieve the value for the key lookup. [Upload you plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: Off-topic - belongs on dba

Comment: A key lookup is normally not a problem I would say. Is the number of times that the key lookup will execute too big, that you are saying you like to fix it? Could you share your execution plan and some more details?

Comment: Thanks for above comments. I've attached the execution plan and extra info to my original post. hope that helps, thanks.

Comment: An image of an execution plan is nearly useless. See the link above to paste the actual plan so others can actually see the details.

Comment: Link to Query Execution plan now attached in OP.